# The Mac won't let me import photos from my iphone

Tags: iphone, import

I am trying to import my photos from my iphone to my mac and even though i already put trust this computer, the mac insists that i haven't done it yet. i have done it many times and its still not working. Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using, and what application are you trying to import the photos into? One thing to keep in mind is you have to unlock your phone when the trust message appears.

Comment: I am using the Photos app on a MacBookPro and i already put trust while it was unlocked. Still nothing

Comment: Thank you for the advice from above comments. Resetting my Location and Privacy and pressing Trust when prompted on my phone actually fixed the problem of uploading my photos from my IPhone 6 to my IMac Computer. Thank you again, this advice was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

On your iphone, go to Settings > General > Reset > **Reset Location & Privacy**.

Plug in your iPhone via the USB to your mac.

On your iPhone when prompted press "Trust".

You should now be able to import.

Comment: This fixed the problem I had been having with an iPhone 5 running iOS 10.3.3 syncing to a MacBook Pro running Mac OSX 10.9.5. I'm intrigued to know why the problem appeared and why the fix worked, but thank you anyway.

Comment: This totally works but one has to wonder why it's needed at all, after **months** of using a specific macbook and a specific iPhone together, without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't specified the version of macOS you're running, this advice will be somewhat general in nature.

On the Mac there are a number of ways to import photos. You don't explain how you've tried to import them, but have you tried using the Image Capture app or either the iPhoto and/or Photos apps (depending on what OS you have installed) instead of what you normally try?

**[EDIT - Sometimes trying a different approach will trigger the Trust computer prompt and this will be accepted/remembered for next time]**

These apps can be found within your Applications folder. The one you use will depend on how you want to manage your photos:

- **Image Capture** provides a way for you to just import your photos to your Mac's hard drive to access and use as you wish. By default they will import to your Pictures folder, but you can select other locations as well as create subfolders.
- **iPhoto and/or Photos** are apps that not only import your photos, but allow you to manage and organise them into albums, produce books, etc.

Regardless of the option you choose, all these apps will recognise your iPhone when it is connected via USB to your Mac. You need to just select the device from the app and import the photos.

These options are separate to iTunes and, in effect, just treat your iPhone as a camera.

**EDIT**
[This edit adds info about dealing with the 'trust computer' issue]

If trying one of the 'other' methods listed above still doesn't work for you, then the trick may be to get the prompt for the iPhone to trust the computer to pop up instead. You can try:

1. Turn off your iPhone
2. Connect the iPhone to your Mac via USB
3. Open iTunes
4. Switch on your iPhone
5. iTunes should then prompt you about the iPhone trusting the computer (instead of the iPhone prompting you)
6. Confirm that you want to trust the computer
7. On the iPhone prompt that follows, also trust the computer

Hopefully the next time you attempt to use image capture/iPhoto/Photos to import photos you won't have a problem.

However, if you do still have a problem, you can also try resetting your iPhone's Network settings. You do this by:

1. Navigate to Settings
2. Tap on General
3. Swipe up and tap on Reset at the bottom of the screen
4. Tap on Reset network settings

Keep in mind once you've reset your Network settings you will need to reenter any WiFi passwords again you normally connect to.

Comment: Photos requires the computer to be trusted by the device just as iTunes does. It knows that iPhone is not just a camera.

Comment: @tubedogg Thanks for picking up on that. I've edited my answer to be somewhat more thorough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i already tried all of your options but its still not working. :( I want to try resetting network settings but im afraid i will lose something. Are you sure it is totally safe?

Comment: Yes. Resetting Network settings is totally Safe. More specifically, what this does is reset WiFi networks and passwords, cellular settings, and VPN and APN settings that you’ve used before. For the majority of people all they will notice is having to reconnect to WiFi networks again. This option is used usually because of problems connecting to the internet, either via WiFi or cellular, but it also helps for less common issues like yours, problems accessing voicemail, etc. I can't guarantee this will fix your problem, but I've seen it work for others.